# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of: $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0&0\\0&-a&0\\0&0&-a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&0&0\\0&-a&0\\0&0&-a\end{bmatrix}$$

I have used the equation: $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ to find the following eigenvalues: $a,-a,-a$. Now I am tasked with finding the eigenvectors using the equation  $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

For the eigenvalue $a$: I am finding the eigenvector to be trivial as I am getting

$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

However the [solution](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/%7Epassage/resources/prelim/Quantum/UndergradQuantum2Workshops_Sol.pdf) indicates the following eigenvectors should be calculated:

$$|\alpha \rangle= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\quad,\quad|\alpha_2 \rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}\quad,\quad|\alpha_3 \rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Could you explain what steps you followed to get the eigenvector $(0,0,0)^T$?

Comment: Yeah, the zero vector is never counted as an eigenvector. $A\vec 0=\lambda \vec 0$ for all $\lambda.$

Comment: What exactly is happening when you find that the only eigenvector for $a$ is the zero vector? I don't think we can say much more than that you're obviously making a mistake there.

Comment: If you ignore what? The $\vec 0?$ You have two eigenvalues, but three eigenvectors here easily.

Comment: By the way, the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are the diagonal entries

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, if we ignore the $0$ eigenvector for the eigenvalue of $a$, we only have two eigenvalues (-a) and (-a) how would we find 3 eigenvectors with that?

Comment: No, we have an eigenvector for $a$ which is not zero, @JackJack

Comment: for  $\lambda=-a$, the solution space to $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ is two-dimensional